# How to combine multiple series types(bar and line) in a chart using Crystal Report

Tags: charts, crystal-reports

I've tried to use two series type in my chart but I don't know how, it's my first time using Crystal Report so i don't know if it's possible. I've seen some questions here in stackoverflow but they are saying i need to right click in my chart ->'Chart Options' -> 'Axis' but when i click there are just 3 options.

Template
General
Titles

I don't know if my version is updated and this action does not exist.
I believe i dont need to put any code here but if i need just tell me ok?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: i don't know crystal reports, but it might be useful to know what version you are using, to know if it needs updated.

Comment: I believe my version is not out of date, but the version of the question i saw. The version of my crystal reports in webconfig is Version=13.0.2000.0

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you want to show some of the data as lines and some of the data as bars, if that is the case, follow these steps:

- go to Preview mode for the report in the designer
- right click on the bar that you wish to change to a line and choose Series Options
- in the Show Selected Series As dialogue, choose Line
  If you want to show all data as lines AND bars, then you should take a look at [this](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1483616).

Hope that helps,

Chris
EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of a report I quickly put together. I have 3 axis and 2 are bar and one is line. Unfortunately one axis has no data. I used the steps from above and it works just fine.
[image]

EDIT 2:
Here are screenshots of the process:

1. Insert the chart
   [image]
2. Select a bar of the chart
   [image]
3. Choose the display type
   [image]

   4. One axis now showing as a line
      [image]

That's the best I can do for you.

EDIT 2:

After a lengthy email exchange, it turned out that he is trying to do this in Crystal Reports for Visual Studio. Unfortunately you can't do it in VS, at least up to version 2010. I suggested a workaround ([link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1743aabd-515f-4396-9227-e9d8e4d86562/mixing-barsline-charts?forum=vscrystalreports)) in hopes that he can achieve his goal. Maybe an inquiry to SAP will shed some more light on this.

Comment: Yes, I want to show some datas in line and some datas in bar but when I insert the chart I can choose the chart type but i want two series. For example: Y axis(left) i want the quantity of money I spent, X axis the month i spent, and Y axis(right) quantity the products i bought. The quantity of money i'll show in bar and the products in line.

Comment: Then follow the steps in my answer. It is important that you are in preview mode so you can select individual bars. And you can start out with either a line or bar chart.

Comment: I cant select each bar, i need to make some configuration but i have no idea anymore.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your chart?

Comment: I dont' have reputation to post, is there any other way?

Comment: I saw your picture and that's exactly what i want to do, the second chart, but can't anyway.

Comment: I did that using the steps outlined in my answer. I'm not sure where you are going wrong.

Comment: Can you put the picture step by step of the steps you put above? Because i can see the picture but i can't put my pictures.

Comment: I saw your example but in my case i can't select the serie i want to be line, you have an email that i can send you my chart?

Comment: Just one more question, you are using an external editor for your crystal reports or you are using through visual studio?

Comment: I sent you an email with the pictures!

Comment: It looks like you are not clicking the bar first. See my second picture above. Left-click on a bar in the chart so you see a frame around it, THEN right-click on it to get the option.